# Owl Carousel Keyboard Navigation

Tags: plugins, jquery

I'm looking to add keyboard navigation to the Owl Carousel plugin. The original jQuery plugin's Github has a thread on this topic [here](https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel/issues/65), so I've tried the following:

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');

$(document.documentElement).keyup(function(event) {
if (event.keyCode == 37) {
    owl.prev();
} else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
    owl.next();
}
});
```

Others used #owl-carousel as the selector, but in the Wordpress version it has a string of ever-changing numbers attached to it, so I didn't want to touch that. I don't think using the class will make a difference as they both target the main carousel div.

No matter what I try, I'm getting an "undefined is not a function".

I have tried using my theme's "raw js" input in visual composer, and editing the plugin's source files. I'm not sure if this is Wordpress-specific, or if I'm overlooking something very obvious. Any insight would be much appreciated!

I'm using the carousel here:
http://hammacklawfirm.com/wp/about-paul/

Comment: First off: are you sure your script is executing before the owl carousel script is being loaded ? I see you've placed your code in the header of your site, but I couldn't see where the owl carousel script is being loaded.

Comment: Great insight and thanks for your reply. The theme I am using seems to place any "raw js" from visual composer into the head, which is why I tried editing the plugin's file instead. @Leroy99's suggestion solved the problem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try putting your owl variable inside the function, something like this:

```
jQuery(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {    

    var owl = jQuery(".owl-carousel");

    // handle cursor keys
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
       // go left
       owl.trigger('owl.prev');
    } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
       // go right
       owl.trigger('owl.next');
    }

});
```

It works for me this way.

Comment: In the latest version of Owl, the correct triggers are `prev.owl` and `next.owl`. ([link](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html))

Comment: I needed to trigger "next.owl.carousel" and "prev.owl.carousel" with my version of Owl Carousel. Others might need to do that too.

Comment: How to make the slides move only when the user is seeing the slider, Currently when the user keys up or down while anywhere else on the page, the slides will move?

Comment: I had to tweak it slightly and use `owl.find('.owl-prev').click();` but thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

Din's answer got me started in the right direction, but it looks like Owl changed the [Events](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html) syntax: owl.prev and owl.next aren't working for me. This is, though:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
    owl.owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
    });

    /*keyboard navigation*/
    $(document.documentElement).keyup(function(event) {    
        if (event.keyCode == 37) { /*left key*/
            owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [700]);
        } else if (event.keyCode == 39) { /*right key*/
            owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel', [700]);
        }
    });

});
```