# Owl Carousel Keyboard Navigation with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

I'm trying to do  slider, that users can navigate it by right and left arrow of keyboard.
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856300/owl-carousel-keyboard-navigation)
I've recently read this question, but it seems owlcarousel's architecture have been changed.

```js
import React from "react";
import OwlCarousel from "react-owl-carousel";
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css";
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css";
function App() {
  document.body.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    const owl = document.querySelector(".owl-theme");
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    if (event.keyCode === 37) {
      /*left key*/
      //How can I trigger prev button???
    } else if (event.keyCode === 39) {
      /*right key*/
      //How can I trigger  the next button?
    }
  });

  return (
    <>
      <OwlCarousel
        item="3"
        nav
        autoplay
        className="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded"
      >
        <div className="item">hi</div>
        <div className="item">hi</div>
        <div className="item">hi</div>
        <div className="item">hi</div>
        <div className="item">hi</div>
        <div className="item">hi</div>
        <div className="item">hi</div>
        <div className="item">hi</div>
        <div className="item">hi</div>
      </OwlCarousel>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must set variable that will find your carousel:

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
```

Then call trigger in this way:

```
// Go to the next item
$('.customNextBtn').click(function() {
    owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
});
// Go to the previous item
$('.customPrevBtn').click(function() {
    // With optional speed parameter
    // Parameters has to be in square bracket '[]'
    owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [300]);
});
```

More about triggers you will find here:
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html
Look for event with Type: triggerable
All of them can be called as `owl.trigger('event-name');`

Your code must be thomething as that:

```
if (event.keyCode === 37) {
      /*left key*/
      owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
    } else if (event.keyCode === 39) {
      /*right key*/
      owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
    }
```

And one more thing) You detect carousel by classname: `document.querySelector(".owl-theme")`
So triggers will be attachhed on all carousels with this classname at the same time.
Best way will be detect owl by id - it will call triggers only in one carousel with one id. For example:

```
<div id="myCarousel1" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
document.getElementById('myCarousel1');
```